# Move one linearlayout childs to another by animation

Tags: java, android, android-layout, animation, android-linearlayout

I want to move one linearlayout Childs to another by animation and let the user choose views of a Words linearlayout and make a Sentence at top Like Duolingo app.
this is what I'm exactly want to do:

[image: Animate views from bottom to top]

anybody know a way to do this, not important to use Linearlayout .. can I use any library to do something like this?

Comment: any solution for this?